# Responsive flex modal

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I am having trouble with making my modal a responsive flex box. I'm not really sure on how to make it flexible so could someone help me?

Here is what's happening since it's not responsive
[image]

HTML

```
<div class = "modal" id = "modal">
<div class = "modal-img">
    <img src = "eunbi.jpg" alt = "kwon eunbi" class = "modal-size">
<ul class = "profile-info">
    <li class = "name">Kwon Eunbi</li>
    <li class = "text-style">Birthday: September 27, 1995</li>
    <li class = "text-style">Position: Leader, Main Dancer, Lead Vocalist</li>
    <li class = "text-style">Rank: 7</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal{
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
border: 1px solid black;
background: white;
z-index: 10;
width: 900px;
max-width: 80%;
}

.modal-img{
display: flex;
}

.modal.active{
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.modal-size{
     max-width:60%;
}
```

When the window is resized the image can take a maximum size of 60% width. So the test and image appear in same row.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Consider adding an explanation to your answer to show how the code addresses the problem/question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)` for smaller screens . Add this code for `@media`

- Add `class = "profile-info"` a property to `float:none` so that it positioned below image if screen is small also

And  this code to main CSS

- Use soft code for height and width of class `modal-size` such as
  `.modal-size{width:50%;height:50%}`

Answer (score 0):

Place a `max-width: 50%;` on your flex child elements, then to keep from having to add a media query you can add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the flex parent. Then when the 50% auto is *breaking*, the two elements will wrap stacking on top of each other.

```css
.modal-img {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.profile-info {
   list-style: none;
   margin-top: 1rem;
}

.profile-info,
.modal-size {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-img">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/250/250/any" alt="kwon eunbi" class="modal-size">
    <ul class="profile-info">
      <li class="name">Kwon Eunbi</li>
      <li class="text-style">Birthday: September 27, 1995</li>
      <li class="text-style">Position: Leader, Main Dancer, Lead Vocalist</li>
      <li class="text-style">Rank: 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you mean from *flex responsive*.

*edit below the original answer after you clarified*/

- is the layout supposed to be modified and stack figure and caption?
- is the image supposed to shrink ?
- is the text supposed to shrink ?
- is the text supposed to be layed on top the picture ?
- Else?

However, you can start with `flex-wrap`(to avoid mediaquerie), then look at `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis` , `min-width`/`max-width`, `object-fit` can also be usefull to know about (for video/img), `aspect-ratio` could also be used ...
here is an example wrapping /stacking elements:*(mediaquerie is already proposed in another answer)*

```css
* {/* reset you probably already have */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.modal-img {
  display: flex;
/*added possible example without mediaquerie */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.modal-img img,
.modal-img ul {
  flex-grow: 1;/* they share equally the space or the full row */
  min-width: 50%;/* for img*/
  object-fit:cover;/* for img */
  max-height: 70vh;/* if any value here is suitable or needed */
  margin: auto;/* or use justify-content/align-items on the flex parent */
}
/* end added */
.modal.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal active" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1027/200/200" alt="kwon eunbi" class="modal-size">
    <ul class="profile-info">
      <li class="name">Kwon Eunbi</li>
      <li class="text-style">Birthday: September 27, 1995</li>
      <li class="text-style">Position: Leader, Main Dancer, Lead Vocalist</li>
      <li class="text-style">Rank: 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you can clarify the behavior you expect, it will be usefull to you.

---

**edit after you commented**

> Yes the layout supposed to be modified and stack figure and caption. I want both the picture and text to shrink together.

```css
* {/* reset you probably already have */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.modal-img {
  display: flex;
}
/* added */
.modal-img img,
.modal-img ul {
  flex-grow: 1;/* they share equally the space or the full row */
  max-width: 50%;  
  font-size: calc( 6px + 2vw );/* will shrink expand */
  /*or the use of clamp to set a min/max size */
  font-size: clamp( 8px, calc( 6px + 2vw ), 1.2rem) ; /* will shrink not less than 8px and expand not more than 1.2rem and will resize in between those 2 values */
  margin: auto ;/* or use justify-content/align-items on the flex parent */
  padding:0
}
.text-style {
padding-left:0.75em;
font-size:0.9em;
}
/* end added */
.modal.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal active" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1027/200/200" alt="kwon eunbi" class="modal-size">
    <ul class="profile-info">
      <li class="name">Kwon Eunbi</li>
      <li class="text-style">Birthday: September 27, 1995</li>
      <li class="text-style">Position: Leader, Main Dancer, Lead Vocalist</li>
      <li class="text-style">Rank: 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes the layout supposed to be modified and stack figure and caption. I want both the picture and text to shrink together.

Comment: @bliss okay, then calc() can help shrinking text-size and max-width to shrink img down. added a snippet to demonstrate the idea

Comment: @bliss clamp() is also a possibility for font-size.